# SQL Server SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-agent, database-engine

I'm looking to schedule some scripts from my SQL Server 2012 installation. I have installed the SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351, since that is the full version, not express.  It didnt install a Database Engine though. I went back and installed the SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe database engine only, but when I go to start the SQL Agent service, I get the error "The edition of SQL Server that installed this service does not support SQL Server Agent"

Did I use the wrong database engine? Or install in the wrong order?

Comment: Simply put, SQL Server Agent is not included in the Express version.  It is installed with the Database Engine (not Management Studio).

Comment: Is there a database engine (not express) that I can download for free?

Comment: If you have an MSDN license (or a Technet subscription, I think), you should be able to download and install the Developer Edition for free.  It's got all the functionality of Enterprise Edition.  I think you may also be able to buy it for a nominal cost.  Check out the license agreement, though--you can't use it for production.

Comment: **Express** is the only free server-based edition of SQL Server, but it does **NOT** include SQL Server Agent

Answer (score 0):

While the first comment is correct. I believe you can schedule scripts from Windows Task Scheduler utilizing the sqlcmd utility even on SQL Server Express.